# request for member 'latitude' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, struct

I'd like a user to enter the info into the array of structures but instead getting the 4 same type errors which is:

```
request for member 'locName' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'locDesc' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'latitude' in something not a structure or union|
request for member 'locName' in something not a structure or union|
```

in lines:

```
        printf("Please enter the name for the location: \n");
        scanf("%s\n", &*myArray->locName); //Gets the user input for the Location Name
        printf("Now enter the description:");
        scanf("%s\n", &*myArray->locDesc); //Gets the user input for the Location Description
        printf("Now enter the value for the latitude:");
        scanf("%lf\n", &*myArray->latitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude
        printf("Now enter the value for the longitude:");
        scanf("%lf\n", &*myArray->longitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude
```

Could somebody point to the mistake in the code that I have made? **Note that if the array is full, I need to resize() the size of the array!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//structure Location
typedef struct Location{
    char locName[35];
    char locDesc[85];
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} LocationArray;

//Menu that receives the user input
//and performs corresponding operations based
//on the menu choice
void printMenu(LocationArray **myArray, int *count, int max){
    printf("Hello! Please choose from the menu: ");
    printf("\nType 'A' or 'a' for adding additional location to the array");
    printf("\nType 'P' or 'p' for printing the current list of locations");
    printf("\nType 'Q' or 'q' to quit the program");

    char input = 0;
    scanf("%c", &input);

    //Handles the invalid character input
    //exits if the character does not correspond
    //to the valid menu option
    if(input != 'A' || input != 'a'
       || input != 'P' || input != 'p'
       || input != 'Q' || 'q'){
            printf("Invalid character! Try again!");
            exit(0);
    }
    //Calls other functions
    //based on the character input
    else{
        switch(input){
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
            addInfo(*myArray, *count, max); //Calls function that adds more locations into the array
            break;

        case 'P':
        case 'p':
            printList(*myArray); //Calls the function that prints the current list of locations
            break;
        case 'Q':
        case 'q':
            quitProgram(); //Calls the function that terminates the program
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Adds info into the array of structures
void addInfo(LocationArray **myArray, int *count, int max){
    if(*count == max){ // Checks if the array is already full
        resizeArray(*myArray, max); //Resizes the array if it's full
    }
    else{ //Else, a used fills it out
        printf("Please enter the name for the location: \n");
        scanf("%s\n", &*myArray->locName); //Gets the user input for the Location Name
        printf("Now enter the description:");
        scanf("%s\n", &*myArray->locDesc); //Gets the user input for the Location Description
        printf("Now enter the value for the latitude:");
        scanf("%lf\n", &*myArray->latitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude
        printf("Now enter the value for the longitude:");
        scanf("%lf\n", &*myArray->longitude); //Gets the user input for the Latitude

        *count++; //Increment the count
    }
}

//Resizes(doubles) the array size if the max limit is achieved
int resizeArray(LocationArray **myArray, int numberOfLoc){
    LocationArray *temp;
    temp = (LocationArray*)realloc(*myArray, numberOfLoc*sizeof(LocationArray));

    //Checks if the memory heap is exhausted
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("The memory heap is exhausted!");
        return 0; //returns 0 that represents the heap is exhausted
    }
    else{
        *myArray = temp;
        free(myArray);
        return 1; //If the heap is not exhausted, then return 1 (success)
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("How many locations would you like to be inside the array?\n");
    int numberOfLoc = 0; //variable for storing the size of the LocationArray
    scanf("%d", &numberOfLoc); //gets the user input and stores in numerOfLoc

    LocationArray *myArray; //declares a LocationArray with the size of numberOfLoc
    myArray = (LocationArray*)malloc(numberOfLoc*sizeof(LocationArray));

    //Print the menu
    int count = 0;
    printMenu(&myArray, &count, numberOfLoc);

    //Free the pointer
    free(myArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ensure to use english words and not text speak, SMB means something different to some people.

Comment: Try getting rid of the '&'.

Comment: @MartinJames, tried long ago, same thing :(

Comment: @MartinJames, I guess I have problems with the pointers. Im not handling them probably correctly

Comment: Try `&((*myArray)->locName)`

Comment: Also `free(*myArray);` in `resizeArray()`

Comment: @chux, thanks, it works! But why and how does it work this way :) ?!

Comment: @John C's operator precedence can be confusing.  When code  behaves wrong, review complex operations like `&*myArray->locName` and parenthesize them to get the correct effect.  Evidently, based on the error message, the compiler interpreted it something like  `&(*(myArray->locName))` or something.  There are various on-line precedence lists you can review.  For me - I use `()` on unusual constructs.

Comment: Hopefully the `free(*myArray);` fix is self evident.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @chux. One last question - im getting a `warning:conflicting types for 'addInfo'`, I've been trying to declare the method in the very top like this: `void addInfo(LocationArray**, int*, int);` but getting error. Any suggestions would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: One question per post - so better not to extend the conversation - but hint: carefully review types passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an array of struct , we need an index to specify the specific struct you are going to add to in addInfo, look at the last line in this extract and replace the 0 in mvArrav[0] with mvArrav[i]  where i is the index. You need to modify your logic to pass the index.

```
 void addInfo(LocationArray **myArray, int *count, int max){
  if(*count == max){ // Checks if the array is already full
    resizeArray(*myArray, max); //Resizes the array if it's full
  }
   else{ //Else, a used fills it out
    printf("Please enter the name for the location: \n");
    scanf("%s\n", myArray[0]->locName); //Gets the user input for the Loca
```